# Ruby on Rails: Uninitialized constant in a brand new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have done a search here in Stack before posting, as I have seen so many results with the same error. But, even I tried all the fixes, nothing worked. I have also deleted the entire project 3 times and tried to do different things. I have at this moment followed EXACTLY the same as the documentation (below) on Ruby on Rails Guide says. As soon as I change the root in routes.rb everything stops with the error uninitialized constant StaticPages.

Here is my code inside "routes.rb"

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/index'

  root 'static_pages/#index'
end
```

The command I used to generate the controller

```
$ rails generate controller StaticPages index
```

I have followed the step by step exactly as it are. And no way to work. I have no idea more what to do.

> static_pages_index_path   GET /static_pages/index(.:format)
>   static_pages#index
>
> root_path GET /    static_pages/#index
>
> rails_service_blob_path   GET /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)
>   active_storage/blobs#show
>
> rails_blob_representation_path    GET /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)
>   active_storage/representations#show
>
> rails_disk_service_path   GET /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)  active_storage/disk#show
>
> update_rails_disk_service_path    PUT /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)  active_storage/disk#update
>
> rails_direct_uploads_path POST    /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)
>   active_storage/direct_uploads#create

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-blog-application

Comment: Please post the full error message. Where does it say the error originates from? Open that file. What code is there?

Comment: Hi @TomLord the Controller file is just with the default code the rails generate for us. Declaring the Controller's class. The error is just as describe above, Routing Error and uninitialized constant StaticPages Rails.root (plus the routes I have described). Also its says that "Action Controller: Exception caught".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, an "Uninitialized constant" error originating when trying to find a controller occurs as a result of a mismatch between the module name and the file name, as Rails will try to autoload the controller based on the it's name. Check the following:

1. You have a file named `app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb`
2. The above file starts with `class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController`

Another potential issue is that the syntax in your routes file is incorrect. You should not include a `/` in your `root` definition. Try changing it to:

```
root to: 'static_pages#index'
```

Comment: Hi @Ryan Brunner, yes. The file names are OK. The problem was with the '/'. Thanks!